# Custom Search in 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, search

I have requirement where I need to come up with a webpart with a listbox where user will enter product name/s(multiple items should be allowed).

I am planning to create custom webpart with list box and button and on click of button, I will call SharePoint search query which in turn returns me the search results with required metadata info.

Now my question is how I can bind this results in SharePoint display template or how I can render this results?

Is it good idea to add the template in webpart or can I create new display template? If I create new template how I can map the results from search results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search Box Webpart with Search Results Webpart to develop your solution.

Create a search query within Search Box to obtain relevant indexed data. Use KQL to perform the query

develop a custom display template to style your search results.

This article might help you :
http://dinushaonline.blogspot.com/2014/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-search.html

Let me know if you need further information